# Avoid circular dependency with subclass declaration

Tags: c++, class, include

I have a circular dependency. In general this is solvable by forward declaration. However in my case  I seem to be unable to forward-declare.

File hook.h:

```
class Hook : public Object {
public:
    enum class Type {
        …
    };

…
}
```

File object.h:

```
class Hook;

class Object {
    …
    void notifyHooks(Hook::Type type, const std::string &arg);
…
}
```

An obvious attempt of a forward declaration would be `enum class Hook::Type;`. However, it doesn't work. Would `Hook` be a namespace, one could write:

```
namespace Hook {
    enum class Type;
}
```

However, this notation fails for the class case. Here, it would not be seen as a forward declaration anymore but rather as a (quite empty) full declaration of `Hook`.

How to properly resolve this problem?

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do with forward declaration. Also, it is a symptom of a defective design. You may want to find ways of moving `notifyHooks` to `Hook` or some other place to remove the circular dependency problem.

Comment: Why would you say my design is defective? It works perfectly well with defining enum class HookType outside of Hook for that matter.

Comment: It is defective only if `Hook` is meant to be a sub-type of `Object`. If not, you can `#include "Hook.h"` in `Object.h` and there won't be a problem. If `Hook` is meant to be a sub-type of `Object`, then you cannot use the details of what's inside the class `Hook` in the interface of `Object`.

Comment: You have described that `Object` depends on `Hook` because of the `enum`. How does `Hook` depend on `Object`? Someone may be able to give you a suggestion based on the other dependency.

Comment: Hook is derived from Object :). This is what I added recently so I can't do the include the other way round anymore. I have to live with the HookType enum staying outside the class I guess.